# How can one supply credentials during a Fetch call?

Tags: libgit2sharp

We're not talking about SSH since it's not yet implemented, but how can I supply credentials for the repository before I perform a fetch via HTTP/HTTPS? There doesn't seem to be a parameter for a Credentials instance, and nothing when constructing a Repository instance for storing credentials.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within the **FetchFixture.cs** file, there is a **[Fetch() test using credentials](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/FetchFixture.cs#L52-L74)**:

```
    [SkippableFact]
    public void CanFetchIntoAnEmptyRepositoryWithCredentials()
    {
        InconclusiveIf(() => string.IsNullOrEmpty(Constants.PrivateRepoUrl),
            "Populate Constants.PrivateRepo* to run this test");

        string repoPath = InitNewRepository();

        using (var repo = new Repository(repoPath))
        {
            Remote remote = repo.Network.Remotes.Add(remoteName, Constants.PrivateRepoUrl);

            // Perform the actual fetch
            repo.Network.Fetch(remote, new FetchOptions
            {
                Credentials = new Credentials
                    {
                        Username = Constants.PrivateRepoUsername,
                        Password = Constants.PrivateRepoPassword
                    }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks. I don't feel comfortable messing with your guy's source yet, so I'll put in an issue, instead ;)

Comment: @JanWillemB The test has been since moved into **[FetchFixture.cs](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/FetchFixture.cs#L52-L74)**

Comment: @nulltoken thanks, fixed the link and copied the test.

Comment: This API is obsolete, use [CredentialsProvider instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26177459/305092)