# LibGit2Sharp fetching error "Too many redirects or authentication replays"

Tags: libgit2sharp

I receive the error “Too many redirects or authentication replays” when trying to fetch with libgit2sharp from a TFS server.

I've tried the solutions in the article below and none seem to be working.

[LibGit2Sharp: Fetching fails with "Too many redirects or authentication replays"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26145023/libgit2sharp-fetching-fails-with-too-many-redirects-or-authentication-replays)

code using DefaultCredentials():

```
        CredentialsHandler credHandler = (_url, _user, _cred) => new DefaultCredentials();
        var fetchOpts = new FetchOptions { CredentialsProvider = credHandler };

        using (var repo = GetRepository())
        {
            Remote remote = repo.Network.Remotes["origin"];
            repo.Network.Fetch(remote, fetchOpts);
        }   // using
```

Comment: Could you please update your questions with details regarding the git server you're trying to interact with (TFS, Stash, Github, ...)?

Comment: @nulltoken sure thing, updated to show it's a TFS server, thanks!

Comment: This **[comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26145023/libgit2sharp-fetching-fails-with-too-many-redirects-or-authentication-replays#comment41046164_26177459)** from @EdwardThomson hints at using a `DefaultCredentials`. You wrote that you tried this. Is this correct? Can you share a sample repro code?

Comment: Added my code using DefaultCredentials, very possible I did something wrong there as I actually get a 401 error from that, any advice you can give would be amazing.

Comment: Also want to note that I'm using Git version 1.9.5, not sure if there could be an issue because of that.

Comment: Can you please paste the command line you're using to clone it through git?

Comment: Hmm, sorry but I'm not sure I understand, I normally clone the repo through Visual Studio but from the command line I just use git clone and then the repo's URL. As far as getting the repo within the libgit2sharp program I just use:

var repo = new Repository(_ConfigurationReader.ReadConfigValue("repository.Path"));
return repo;

Comment: And your repository url starts with "https://", correct? What's the version of LibGit2Sharp (Output of `GlobalSettings.Version`)?

Comment: How do you connect with this repository/server with command-line git?

Comment: LibGit2Sharp version is 0.22.0-pre20150606092322 and the repo is http only, no https, could that be the issue?